# Audacity, Openshot, Ardour fail to launch 12.04 precise

Tags: 12.04, segmentation-fault, audacity

I'm using a Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GHz × 2, with GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2  graphics. 32 bit.

I have been using Audacity fine in 10.10, and 11.10 but since upgrading to 12.04 precise, it fails to load. Same experience with Openshot and Ardour.

The other media players; totem, rhythmbox work as normal.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing. No Luck.

Trying to open Audacity from the terminal ('cause nothing happens when clicking the icon), I get this message:

```
(Audacity:2236): Gnome-WARNING **: Accessibility: failed to find module 'libgail-gnome' which is needed to make this application accessible
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES      failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES   failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES   failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES   failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

With Openshot, I get:

```
------------------------- ERROR 1 ------------------------------
Failed to import 'from openshot import main'
Error Message: cannot import name main
----------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------
   OpenShot (version 1.4.0)
--------------------------------
Process no longer exists: 3949.  Creating new pid lock file.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

With Ardour, I get:

```
WARNING: Your system has a limit for maximum amount of locked memory!
     This might cause Ardour to run out of memory before your system runs
     out of memory. You can view the memory limit with 'ulimit -l', and it
     is normally controlled by /etc/security/limits.conf

Ardour 2.8.12
   (built using 10144 and GCC version 4.6.1)
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Paul Davis
Some portions Copyright (C) Steve Harris, Ari Johnson, Brett Viren, Joel Baker

Ardour comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it 
under certain conditions; see the source for copying conditions.
loading default ui configuration file /etc/ardour2/ardour2_ui_default.conf
loading user ui configuration file /home/user/.ardour2/ardour2_ui.conf
Loading ui configuration file /etc/ardour2/ardour2_ui_dark.rc
   theme_init() called from internal clearlooks engine                             ardour: [INFO]: Ardour will be limited to 4096 open files

 loading system configuration file /etc/ardour2/ardour_system.rc
    ardour: [INFO]: No H/W specific optimizations in use
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm a musician with several projects on the go in these apps, especially Audacity. I NEED them!

Pls Help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, also jack rack would not launch. So I went to [this website](http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=526193&p=4103269#p4103269) and did a translation and here is the answer, it worked for me:

> Found the solution: we must upgrade to the latest version of csladspa.